# Java: displaying ONLY two decimal numbers

Tags: java, decimal

When I click calculate to display a calculation it displays the following answer:

Net Pay 31030.38076923077

How can I make it only display two decimal numbers after the dot. example $31030.38

Comment: Show code that is displaying currently.

Comment: Show us your code - there are at least two or three alternatives, but which would be easiest to use depends on what you already have...

Comment: Use `DecimalFormat` class, or use a `%.2f` conversion with `printf`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a number to 2 decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779659/convert-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: If you're using `double` values to compute financial values in dollars and cents, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. If you haven't yet read it, check out [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: @DanielPryden: if someone that needs to ask this question here is dealing with actual financial data, then it's someone *else* that is doing it wrong...

Comment: @thkala: Oh, quite likely. But, unfortunately, quite far from impossible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
double f = 31030.38076923077;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(f+"  "+df.format(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal like this

```
double d = 31030.38474923077;
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(dec);
```

Comment: You might want to write a couple of lines on the benefits and disadvantages of `BigDecimal`. There *are* places where `BigDecimal` is needed but taking such a coding and performance hit just *"to be on the safe fide"* is generally *not* reasonable...