# How to add 0 to decimal instead of 12.5 it will be 12.50

Tags: java

```
 public double calculateMPG() {
    double a = (this.myEndMiles - this.myStartMiles);
    return ((a) / (this.gallons));
}
```

How would I make this function spit out 12.50 instead of 12.5

Thanks

Comment: This is only relevant in a *fixed precision* number: i.e. when displaying it as a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a number to 2 decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779659/convert-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Adding a zero to the end of 12.5 so that is prints as 12.50 is a formatting/presentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really make it return 12.50 instead of 12.5 because you are returning a double. Thus, it will be 12.5   . However, you can display it in that way. Here is how:

```
NumberFormat numFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println( numFormat.format(calculateMPG()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%.2f", calculateMPG());
```

Note that this produces a String representation of the formatted number.

The `double` itself makes no difference between 12.5 and 12.50  and 0012.500.

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Note the "`00`", meaning exactly *two decimal places*.

example

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
double d = 4.0;
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```