# I want to display the total purchase as 11.10 and not 11.1

Tags: java, math, precision

Enter the price of the book: $10

Book Cost: $10.00

State Tax Charged: $0.80

County Tax Charged: $0.30

Total Purchase Price: $11.10

Why I'm getting 11.1?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System. in );

        double bookCost = kbd.nextDouble();
        double stateTax = bookCost * 0.08;
        double countyTax = bookCost * 0.03;
        double totalCost = bookCost + stateTax + countyTax;

        System.out.print("Enter the price of the book: $");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Book Cost: $" + bookCost);
        System.out.println("State Tax Charged: $" + stateTax);
        System.out.println("County Tax Charge: $" + countyTax);
        System.out.println("Total Purchase Price: $" + totalCost);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779659/convert-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: You may be looking for `new DecimalFormat("#0.00")`.

Comment: You might also want to have look at JSR-354 http://javamoney.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.out.println( String.format( "%.2f", totalCost ) );