# Double.parseDouble loses a decimal place

Tags: java, android, double, decimal

I´ve encountered a problem that I can not solve. Tried various solutions described on the site with no result.
I´m passing a string “**total**” that translates to 30.00 but on Doubleparse it changes to `30.0`

I need the double to be `30.00` because it has to be added to an arraylist, and also displayed as text, as `30.00` and not as `30.0`

I´ve tried

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
Double number_total = Double.parseDouble(df.format(total));
```

> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class
>   java.lang.String
>       at java.text.NumberFormat.format(NumberFormat.java:304)
>       at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:702)
>       at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
>       at   com.example.jc.salesman.MainActivity.Totais(MainActivity.java:338)
>       at   com.example.jc.salesman.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:235)

```
String strSum = ((String.format("%.2f", Double.toString(sum))));
```

> ERROR: Process: com.example.jc.salesman, PID: 26845
>   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %f can't format
>   java.lang.String arguments
>       at java.util.Formatter.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1489)
>       at java.util.Formatter.transformFromFloat(Formatter.java:2038)
>       at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1465)
>       at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
>       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
>       at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
>       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
>       at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1973)
>       at
>
> com.example.jc.salesman.MainActivity.Totais(MainActivity.java:368)

I even forced Locale in main,

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Please HELP :)

```
public void Total (String total){

    Log.d("log2","total: " + total);// it prints 30.00

    Double number_total = Double.parseDouble(total);

    Log.d("log2","number_total: " + total);// it prints 30.0
    losing a decimal place.

    array_Total.add (number_total); //Arraylist<Double
    sum (double) = sum + number_total;
    String strSum = (Double.toString(sum));
    total.setText (strSum);
}
```

Comment: double `30.0` is the same as double `30.00` or double `30D` - all are the exact same number, just the textual representation is different - it's not a parse problem) - what you want is String `30.00` -  so try `String.format("%.2f", sum);` (formating the double, not the string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779659/convert-a-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `df.format()` wrongly. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format(double,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)), the .format() method of DecimalFormat takes a Number (double, long or Object that is a subclass of Number).

What you can do is to parse and store the double normally(30.0). When you do need to output the double, you can output using String formatter e.g. `String.format("%.2f", val)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.format("%.2f", doubleValue)` to set it to 2 decimal points. But it will roundoff your other decimal values to 2 decimal points(Eg: 30.2345 --> 30.23) as well so if you want to retain decimal values then do it conditionally.

Comment: Thanks I´ve used it. If the string is 30.55 then all writes ok, but when the two decimals are 0 then it writes with only one decimal place.I can live with it and move on.It´s just aesthetic