# How return only two decimals with float?

Tags: java, android, string, decimal

I've got a float value and i need to have only two decimals after comma. I'm using this code:

```
public static float getWhatINeed() {
  StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
  float total = 
      ((float)statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize()) / (1073741824);
  return total;
}
```

And it returns for example: `12.552425` in a textview. I need display something like: `12.55` that is enough for me. I saw this:

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", 1.2975118);
```

somewhere but I can't use it in my case because I use a float value and I need to use float. How could I solve this?

Comment: Seems duplilcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911356/whats-the-best-practice-to-round-a-float-to-2-decimals

Comment: Here [What's the best practice to round a float to 2 decimals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911356/whats-the-best-practice-to-round-a-float-to-2-decimals).

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to limit the number of decimal points in a `float`. A `float` is a `float` and it has an "unlimited" number of decimals. The `String` display of a `float` may be limited to a format only showing a specific number of decimals.

If you really NEED 2 decimals, use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

You basically have 4 options:

- return a `float` and deal with the fact that there are n decimal places
- format to a `String` (which means a lot of string parsing if you need to do calculation)
- convert to use `BigDecimal`
- convert to use `int` and assume that the ones digit represents hundredths.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
new DecimalFormat("00.00").format(1.2975118);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
    float a=1.256f;
    System.out.println(df.format(a));
}
```

Out put

```
1.26
```

Answer (score -3):

After setting precision and get as a `String` You can canvert it back to float by

`float f = Float.parseFloat(YourString);`

Comment: This will not work as it could result in a float equivelant to "1.120000000000000000001". This is why  "This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency"