# How does BigDecimal.valueOf(float) work?

Tags: java, floating-point

I've already looked at [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911683/4671213).

I was a little confused by the behaviour of `BigDecimal.valueOf(float)`. Here's the example:

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(20.2f)); //prints 20.200000762939453
```

Therefore

```
float f = BigDecimal.valueOf(20.2f)
            .setScale(2, RoundingMode.UP)
            .floatValue();
System.out.println(f); //prints 20.21
```

Which is defenitely not the behaviour I expected. Is there a way to `round up` float correctly avoiding such errors?

Comment: Take a look at [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Finite precision floating point numbers inherently can't represent some values. It's somewhat similar to how 1/3 can't be represented exactly in base 10. Here `20.2f != 20.2`.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Very interesting. So I we deal with floating-point arithmetic and want to keep the exact precision, should we perform ROUND_EVEN any time we perform an arithmetic operations on them?

Comment: What is the expected output? It looks correct to me, 20.200000762939453 rounded up to 2 decimal places is 20.21. You could try setting the scale to a larger number with round even and then set to 2 with round up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the description of **float** and how it utilizes the allocated bits see 
[How many significant digits have floats and doubles in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-have-floats-and-doubles-in-java)

BigDecimal works fine and -- as expected -- keeps all digits it received, but it can't guess the precision of the given argument. Therefore:

```
    float f = 20.20f;
    System.out.println("Float: "+f);
    System.out.println("BigDecimal.valueOf: "+BigDecimal.valueOf(f));
    System.out.println("BigDecimal from value: "+new BigDecimal(f, MathContext.DECIMAL32));
    System.out.println("BigDecimal from string: "+new BigDecimal(""+f));;
```

Prints:

```
Float: 20.2
BigDecimal.valueOf: 20.200000762939453
BigDecimal from value: 20.20000
BigDecimal from string: 20.2
```