# How to create a float Field in InfluxDB with 2 decimal

Tags: java, types, influxdb, measurement

I put in my influxDB this Point in java:

```
            dbConnector.write(Point.measurement(machineData.getOpcuaObject())
                .time(machineData.getTimestamp(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addField("value2", round(machineData.getValue().floatValue(),2))
                .tag("sensor", machineData.getSensor())
                .build());
```

But this dont solve the Problem, i dont know why.

if i write into influx so:

```
.addField("value2", round(machineData.getValue().floatValue(),2))
```

i became this:

```
1526622038902000000 0.13704816468572244048 Istdrehm
```

if i write into influx so:

```
.addField("value2", 0.13)
```

i became this:

```
 1526622038902000000 0.13 Istdrehm
```

Why, any idea?

code of round:

```
public static float round(float value, int decimalPlace) {
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(value));
bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
return bd.floatValue();
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you need to debug the Java end of things -- to get the Rounding method correct -- and then the InfluxDB end will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more of a Java question than an InfluxDB question, but since I do both, I thought I'd give an answer. Basically you want to round the number to the nearest 2 decimal places **before** you store it in InfluxDB, since InfluxDB retains all precision.

see this answer: [What's the best practice to round a float to 2 decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911356/whats-the-best-practice-to-round-a-float-to-2-decimals)

for how to round your decimal to 2 significant places before storing that number in InfluxDB.

HTH,
dg

Comment: thx davidgs i tried it out, but this dont solve the problem.

i edit my question with the new code