# Android - Round to 2 decimal places

Tags: android, double, decimal, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I know that there are plenty of examples on how to round this kind numbers.
But could someone show me how to round double, to get value that I can display as a 
String and ALWAYS have 2 decimal places?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html this will be your friend.

Comment: double myNum = 34.393893 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); String twoDigitNum = df.format(myNum);

Answer (score 535, accepted):

You can use `String.format("%.2f", d)`, your double will be rounded automatically.

Comment: yes, this I was looking for, but should be: String.format("%.2f", d), thanks

Comment: A safer way would be to use a DecimalFormat. With your method there is an option that the formatting will go wrong in some countries, which you would never notice as a developer and probably aren't willing to check for.
A better way is to do it like this:
DecimalFormat percentageFormat = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
       String finalPercentage = percentageFormat.format(percentage);

Comment: Be careful of the Locale. In French (Canada), it'll use a comma instead of decimal. Force Locale like this (Example):   

    `String.format(Locale.CANADA, "%.2f", d)`

Comment: But this will convert it to String! :/.

Comment: @usman original question was about converting to String with fixed precision, so there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: Using string format with this method is not safe.  If your app will be used internationally you will start receiving a lot of crash reports.  reporting either NumberFormatExceptions or RuntimeExceptions.  The reason is some countries use a comma as there decimal seperator and others use a period.  useing decimal format or number format is a much safer approach.  Of course forcing locale can be done also, but it may confuse users that are not used to seeing a period as their decimal seperator.

Comment: If you are messed up in certain locales. then this will be the best solution:  `Double rounded= new BigDecimal(myDouble).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();`

Answer (score 13):

One easy way to do it:

```
    Double d;
    Int i;
    D+=0.005;
    i=d*100;
    Double b = i/100;
    String s = b.toString():
```

Comment: By no means this looks easy. Although thumbs up for the try.