# Truncate value after decimal point in android

Tags: android

I want to truncate the value from the given value 32.1500 into 32 and display it on textview text please help me out i searched a lot but did not found anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Round to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366280/android-round-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: sorry the link given for duplicate answers is showing the number with two decimal numbers but i want to truncate the number after decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to cast it you can keep it at double but truncate the trailing zeroes like this:

```
textView.setText(String.format("%.0f", 5.222));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
private final DecimalFormat noDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");

String decimalValue = decimalFormat.format(value);
String noDecimalValue = noDecimalFormat.format(value);
```

Or using NumberFormat instead of DecimalFormat:

```
 private NumberFormat formatter;
 // Set the properties for the number format that will display the values
 formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
 formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
 formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);

 String decimalValue = formatter.format(value);

 formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
 formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

 String noDecimalValue = formatter.format(value);
```

You can set the rounding mode you want like this:

```
noDecimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN)
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cast like this.

```
double number=32.1500;
int numbereditted=(int) number;
textView.setText("Number= "+numbereditted);
```

Or use decimal format.

```
double number=32.1500;
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0");
textView.setText("Number= "+df.format(number));
```

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion won't work as you expected. It will round the number instead of truncating it. So `32.51` will be converted to `33`.