# How to limit decimal digits - Android

Tags: android, numbers, double, decimal, limit

I already searched online and all that I found is using DecimalFormat and I tried it, but when I code on Android Studio, appears a message saying that is necessary to use the API 24 to this kind of command. The API 24 has erros and all the sites I looked, advised to use the API 23.

So, I need a way to show double numbers only with two decimal digits on my AlertDialog.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Ok! It's done!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

referring to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366357/4700782), you can use this code:

```
String formattedValue = String.format("%.2f", myDouble);
```

Let me know if it is what you were looking for

Comment: I tried to use but didn't work, don't know if I used it right, I posted how I used in a comment.

Comment: @Mekillerow String format gives you a string as result, check my edit in the code :)

Comment: @Mekillerow consider selecting the answer that solved your problem as the correct answer, so people having your same problem can find a solution easily

Answer (score 0):

```
 /** Round on two digits after "." */
    public static float round(float f){
        return Math.round(f * 100) / 100.0F;
    }
```

P.S. Use float for short float numbers. Thats what its made for.

**Edit:**
"Ok, with 3 decimal digits its the better too,right? How can I limit those digits?"

Take a quick look how it works for two decimal places. Then its really simple to expand for three.

Comment: In my case use float is better than double then?

Comment: It depends on how exact it your result shall be. If you only need two decimal digits then float is the right choice

Comment: Ok, with 3 decimal digits its the better choice too,right? How can I limit those digits?

Comment: Difference between float and double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java

Comment: Understood, thanks! So in my case is better use float, but where and how should I put the code that you wrote first on my code?? PS: The code is on the comment below