# Android Studio - DecimalFormat (java.text) - Not working properly

Tags: java, android

So, I have this following code to make a simple temperature app converter in Android Studio 4.0.1:

```
bt_converter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    double tempC = Double.parseDouble(et_tempC.getText().toString());

    DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double tempF = Double.parseDouble(arredondar.format(tempC * 1.8 + 32));

    tv_tempF.setText(String.valueOf(tempF));
}
```

The problem is that when I run the app it crashes due to this statement:
DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
And the same for:
DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

In fact it crashes with every pattern started by "0" and involving point "."

I've tried to switch it to:
DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("#,##");

And it actually works but it is not showing two decimal places as intended, and no matter what `tempC` value I put in, the output is always some number point zero `(xx.0)`.

For example:
for `tempC = 10.11111111`
it shows `tempF = 50.0`
When it should give me `50.19` or `50.2` instead.

I've reinstalled the app and cleaned the project, and even changed my windows 10 region settings (with regards to decimal symbols), but it still remains the same.

But please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366280/android-round-to-2-decimal-places) help?

Comment: Please: *ALWAYS* copy/paste the error message text whenever you post a question.  SUGGESTION: Try this format, post back what happens: `"#,#00.0#"`

Comment: Hi, Ann Zen! I'm thankful for your answer.
Unfortunately it didn't work yet because no matter what value I put in for tempC, the app crashes imediately. Maybe something is missing or either wrong in the code because it's not accepting neither "0" or "." in the DecimalFormat pattern. 
But I'm still open to any other suggestions and I appreciate very much your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I came to a solution, and it works as intended.
I just changed the three last lines of code:

Before

```
DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

double tempF = Double.parseDouble(arredondar.format(tempC * 1.8 + 32));
tv_tempF.setText(String.valueOf(tempF));
```

After:

```
DecimalFormat arredondar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double tempF = tempC * 1.8 + 32;

tv_tempF.setText(arredondar.format(tempF));
```

Apparently there is some king of error/incompatibility. But, I realised that I was converting tempF from String to Double with the second line in the before code, and then convert it back again to String with the third one.

So I simply put the tempF directly in the output with a String format, after having calculated it with no convertion:

```
            double tempF = tempC * 1.8 + 32;

            tv_tempF.setText(arredondar.format(tempF));
```

And I've changed the pattern from "#.##" to "0.00" to make sure that I get two decimal places everytime.