# Rounding Double in Java - Minimum Decimal Places

Tags: java, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

The code below works

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args){

    double x = roundTwoDecimals(35.0000);
    System.out.println(x);
}

public static double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {   
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    twoDForm.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
}
```

it results to 35.0.
How to forced the minimum number of decimal places?
The output I want is 35.00

Comment: The number of trailing zeros is not a property of a `double`, it's a property of a `String` representation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7593617/446885

Comment: How to do it without converting to String?

Comment: @JRGalia: You have to convert it to `String`, because your question is about human-readable representations of numbers.

Comment: But if you're asking how to round a `double` value to two decimal digits, the answer is: you can't.

Comment: You will need more #'s at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't working like you expect because the return value of `roundTwoDecimals()` is of type `double`, which discards the formatting you do within the function. In order to achieve what you want, you might consider returning the `String` representation from `roundTwoDecimals()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Converting formatted number back to `double` will make you lose all formatting changes. Change the function to:

```
public static String roundTwoDecimals(double d) {   
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    return twoDForm.format(d);
}
```

EDIT: you were right, "#.00" is correct.

Comment: Actually, `#.##` would make the decimal places optional, which doesn't seem to be what he wants. The advice about returning the `String` is the relevant part.