# Rounding to specific number of digits in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell

I am trying to make a function to round a floating point number to a defined length of digits. What I have come up with so far is this:

```hs
import Numeric;

digs :: Integral x => x -> [x] <br>
digs 0 = [] <br>
digs x = digs (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]

roundTo x t = let d = length $ digs $ round x <br>
                  roundToMachine x t = (fromInteger $ round $ x * 10^^t) * 10^^(-t)
              in roundToMachine x (t - d)
```

I am using the `digs` function to determine the number of digits before the comma to optimize the input value (i.e. move everything past the comma, so `1.234` becomes `0.1234 * 10^1`)

The `roundTo` function seems to work for most input, however for some inputs I get strange results, e.g. `roundTo 1.0014 4` produces `1.0010000000000001` instead of `1.001`.

The problem in this example is caused by calculating `1001 * 1.0e-3` (which returns `1.0010000000000001`)

Is this simply a problem in the number representation of Haskell I have to live with or is there a better way to round a floating point number to a specific length of digits?

Comment: I assume you know that 0.1 is irrational at base two, and will _always_ be represented imprecisely? If you want to round to a specified number of decimals, you need a decimal representation, such as a string.

Comment: Note this isn't a fact of Haskell, identical behaviour will be found in all languages when not dealing in [arbitrary precision types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) which languages *rarely* have as the default. Welcome to the scary part about dealing with financial calculations in software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a haskell problem as much as a floating point problem.  Since each floating point number is implemented in a finite number of bits, there exist numbers that can't be represented completely accurately.  You can also see this by calculating `0.1 + 0.2`, which awkwardly returns `0.30000000000000004` instead of `0.3`.  This has to do with how floating point numbers are implemented for your language and hardware architecture.

The solution is to continue using your `roundTo` function for doing computation (it's as accurate as you'll get without special libraries), but if you want to print it to the screen then you should use string formatting such as the `Text.Printf.printf` function.  You can specify the number of digits to round to when converting to a string with something like

```hs
import Text.Printf

roundToStr :: (PrintfArg a, Floating a) => Int -> a -> String
roundToStr n f = printf ("%0." ++ show n ++ "f") f
```

But as I mentioned, this will return a string rather than a number.

EDIT:

A better way might be

```hs
roundToStr :: (PrintfArg a, Floating a) => Int -> a -> String
roundToStr n f = printf (printf "%%0.%df" n) f
```

but I haven't benchmarked to see which is actually faster.  Both will work exactly the same though.

EDIT 2:

As @augustss has pointed out, you can do it even easier with just

```hs
roundToStr :: (PrintfArg a, Floating a) => Int -> a -> String
roundToStr = printf "%0.*f"
```

which uses a formatting rule that I was previously unaware of.

Comment: This is why printf formatting allows for '*' as the number of digits.

Comment: @augustss Thanks for pointing that out to me, I didn't know of that formatting rule.  I'll edit it into the post.

Answer (score 28):

I realise this question was posted almost 2 years back, but I thought I'd have a go at an answer that didn't require a string conversion.

```
-- x : number you want rounded, n : number of decimal places you want...
truncate' :: Double -> Int -> Double
truncate' x n = (fromIntegral (floor (x * t))) / t
    where t = 10^n

-- How to answer your problem...
λ truncate' 1.0014 3
1.001

-- 2 digits of a recurring decimal please...
λ truncate' (1/3) 2
0.33

-- How about 6 digits of pi?
λ truncate' pi 6
3.141592
```

I've not tested it thoroughly, so if you find numbers this doesn't work for let me know!

Comment: Note that the binding of `truncate'` as shown emits a type-default warning "_Defaulting the type variable ‘a0’ to type ‘Integer’ in the following constraints_". In order to fix it, define `y = floor (x * t) :: Int` and then return `fromIntegral y / t`.

Answer (score 2):

I also think that avoiding string conversion is the way to go; however, I would modify the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952975/5464101) (from [schanq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074279/schanq)) to use [round](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/round_f.html) instead of [floor](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/floor_f.html):

```
round' :: Double -> Integer -> Double
round' num sg = (fromIntegral . round $ num * f) / f
    where f = 10^sg

> round' 4 3.99999
4.0
> round' 4 4.00001
4.0
```