# How to round up my BigDecimal to have 2 digits after the decimal point? (scala)

Tags: java, scala, math

What is the best solution to make my BigDecimal to have 2 digits after the decimal point (while keeping it as precise as possible) in Scala?

```
val bigDec1 = BigDecimal(12345.12)
val bigDec2 = BigDecimal(1345.12)
((bigDec1/bigDec2)*100)
```

The last row is equal to `917.7709051980492446770548352563340` but I want it to be `917.77`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134047/java-bigdecimal-round-to-the-nearest-whole-value (Java solution)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106886/scala-doubles-and-precision  (Scala solution)