# How to display a double or float on a JPanel to only two decimal places

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I have a problem in which I want to draw a string containing a double or float value up to two decimal value. It is easy to do in using `System.out.Printf()` but how to so using `drawString`

like the statement below calculates the number to be deawn on JPanel. but what is actually displayed is a String having values upto 14 decimal places. I need to restrict the display to only 2 decimal places

```
double size= ((int)((((float) maxSize / (float) (40 * 1.0))*100.0))/100.0);

g.drawString("" + size, 135, 100 + range * i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 double inputNumber = 1.234567;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 String printValue = df.format(inputNumber));
 g.drawString(printValue);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.

```
String value= new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this... `java.text.DecimalForamt`

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    decimal d = new decimal("10.2344");
    df.format(d);
```