# how to change the double value as four decimal point value

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

i've got lat and long point like this,

```
x1: 11.955165229802363
y1: 79.8232913017273
```

i need to convert 4 decimal point

```
x1 = 11.9552
y1 = 79.8233
```

Comment: Is this for display purposes or do you want to truncate the value of the digit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

Comment: What is the round mode with this?

Comment: instead of two mathematical operations you create two new objects and call 3 methods only to show 4 digits after dot, so much overhead

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.ceil(x1* 10000) / 10000
```

Replace 10000 with 10^N, where N is number of digits after dot. In case of 4 digits after dot, precision shouldn't be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String.format("%.4f", 11.955165229802363)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to round/truncate the decimal, and speed is not a large consideration, you want to use `BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale)` with `scale` set to 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("#.####"); 
                                           ^^^^
x1= Double.valueOf(dtime.format(x1));
```

Comment: I think you may have forgotten a line here; dtime isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

```
float round = Round(num,4);
System.out.println("Rounded data: " + round);
}

public float Round(float Rval, int Rpl) {
float p = (float)Math.pow(10,Rpl);
Rval = Rval * p;
float tmp = Math.round(Rval);
return (float)tmp/p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display the value like that, use a DecimalFormat to convert the value to a string, then display that.

If you really want to round it to four digits, you can achieve that by multiplying by 10000, rounding, then dividing again.  However, I would advise against it, since not all decimal numbers can be properly represented in floating point format. Changes are you'll just get something like you already had.

If you really want four digits to work with as an internal state, use a BigDecimal instead.  It is properly equipped to do what you want.