# Regarding rounding off a value to certain decimal point

Tags: java, rounding

I was  going through the class decimal format as I was trying format a decimal number in Java upto 2 decimal places or 3 decimal places.

I come up with this solution as shown below but please also let me know are there any other alternative that java provides us to achieve the same thing..!!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DecimalFormatExample {   

    public static void main(String args[])  {

        //formatting numbers upto 2 decimal places in Java
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.14));
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.1454));

        //formatting numbers upto 3 decimal places in Java
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.000");
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.14));
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.1454));
    }

}

Output:
364,565.14
364,565.15
364,565.140
364,565.145
```

Please advise what are other alternatives that java provide us to achieve the same thing..!!

Comment: Is there anything about this solution that you're not happy with?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your problem with the above code is...

Comment: E.g. this question contains a couple of ways to do rounding / truncating / formatting of doubles: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2808535/56285
But if DecimalFormat does what you need, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are bothered by re-defining your `DecimalFormat`, or if you suspect you'll be needing to do redefine many times, you could also do inline formatting with `String.format()`. Check the [syntax for `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) especially the Numeric sub-title.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to round off...

```
double a = 123.564;
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 10.0) / 10.0;
System.out.println(roundOff);
roundOff = Math.round(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(roundOff);
```

The output is

```
123.6
123.56
```

Number of `0`s while multiplying and dividing decides the rounding off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method.

```
float round(float value, int roundUpTo){
     float x=(float) Math.pow(10,roundUpTo);
     value = value*x; // here you will guard your decimal points from loosing
     value = Math.round(value) ; //this returns nearest int value
     return (float) value/p;
}
```