# How to roundup a Double value up to two precision

Tags: java, math

I have a Double value `Double val = 49.569632`

How can I roundup the `val` to get `49.57`

Comment: `Math.round(number*100.0)/100.0;`

Comment: Also keep in mind that Double and double are different things and you probably would want double... unless you really know what you are doing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DecimalFormat`.

```
double d = 4.569632;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Or you can use the below method as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/2024761) as Luiggi Mendoza suggested.

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: It would be better using `BigDecimal` as posted in the possible duplicate Q/As

Comment: DecimalFormat is perfect for my instance. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to round is when printing

```
double val = 49.569632; // this should be a primitive, not an object
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", val);
```

or you can round the value first

```
double rounded = Math.round(val * 1e2) / 1e2;
System.out.println(rounded);
```

IMHO Using `BigDecimal` is slower, more complicated to write and no less error prone than using `double` if you know what you are doing. I know many developer prefer to use a library than write code themselves. ;)