# Formate String after dot "." from a string in java-Android

Tags: android

I have a string like `46542.5435657468`, but i want format this string and need only two charector after dot "." like `46542.54`. Please suggest me which String method i need to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String.format("%.2f", Double.valueOf("46542.5435657468"));
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe `String.format()`?

```
String.format("%.2f", floatValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DecimalFormat`

first declare this at the top

```
DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); //change .## for whatever numbers after decimal you may like.
```

then use it like this

```
dtime.format(your string);
```

like:

```
 String a = "46542.5435657468";
dtime.format(a);
```

output will be `46542.54`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point

Comment: Pankaj Kumar what you mean? my way is okay too

Comment: I didn't said that you are wrong :) your answer is perfect. I just indicating that this question has been answered tooooo many times .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like this.

```
private static String extract(String text) {
    String[] values = text.split(".");
    return values[0] + "." + values[1].substring(0, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method indexOf tell you the position of the character "."  ok?

The method substring cut a peace of the string from the begining (value 0) until the positio of the character "."  plus 2 digits more.

```
public String getNumberFormated(String  yourNumber)
{
   return  yourNumber.substring(0, yourNumber.indexOf(".") + 2);
}
```

Do you like my solution?