# Java reads Double as a String?

Tags: java

In this line:

```
totalCost += df.format(pCost);
```

I get the error 'inconvertable types' required: double, found: string, yet the pCost variable is a double, and the method that made it outputs it as a double.. does anyone know why this may happen?

Comment: Why don't you do `totalCost += pCost;` ?

Comment: I need it to be to 2 decimal places. I don't get why this happens at all though.

Comment: @Chillo you don't round while adding, you round when you have the final value.

Comment: Rounding is presentation, not calculation.

Comment: Yes, `df` is a `DecimalFormat`, which produces a `String`. "Two decimal places" doesn't have any meaning with binary floating point.

Comment: If you're trying to round because you're dealing with money, don't ever use floating-point for money; use a money library (Joda Money) or an integral type of the cents (or other base unit).

Comment: That is the final value, but the unrounded version is used elsewhere furthur along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use just this:

```
totalCost += pCost;
```

or, if you will:

```
totalCost += Double.valueOf(df.format(pCost));
```

see: [Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

edit: as a response to the caveat below: This code isn't truely precise; follow the link for a more accurate version (in short: convert it to a `BigDecimal` and use `.setScale()`)

Comment: I need it to be to 2 dp, hence the df.format

Comment: Saw your comment, and adjusted (and readjusted) my code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, followed that new advice and it seems to have worked! Thanks.

Comment: This code isn't really accurate; even assuming that all of the doubles in question are within a close range, the "rounding" is still subject to re-rounding when the decimal is stuffed back into binary representation; the value `0.10` can't be exactly represented as a binary fraction.

Comment: @Chillo *Seems* to have worked. *Do not* use floating-point for money in production code.

Comment: I know. See the provided link for a more accurate function to round a double to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Seen and bookmarked, ta. This is no where near production code but cheers for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Well Decimal format really does return String:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(34.4959);
```

but to get a Double you could do:

```
Double.valueOf(df.format(34.4959));
```