# Returning a calculation correct to 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I would like the result of this to return correct to 2 decimal places.
ie price = 4.35
ie weightGrams = 233

```
public double pricePerHundredGrams()
{
   return (price * 100) / weightGrams; 
}
```

I would like the calculation to return as 1.86 not 1.86695279....

Comment: The answers to this question should help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: You should probably round when presenting the result, since a `double` knows nothing about the number of "human readable decimals" it contains.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `DecimalFormat` object, and pass in the pattern to parse a `double` into a `String`, representing the value to 2 d.p.

**Example**

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

double val = 1.456;

String formatted = decFormat.format(val);

System.out.println(formatted);

// outputs 1.45
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
double val=1.456;
String s= String.format( "%.2f", val );
System.out.print(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rough but fast way:

```
double result = (price * 100) / weightGrams; 
return ((int) (result * 100)) / 100.0;
```

Comment: If you return an integer, how is this correct to two decimal places?

Comment: result * 100 would be an integer, but since it is divided by 100 it would be a double with 2 decimal places. I'm a bit rusty in Java nowadays since it's been a long time I don't use it, so I'm not sure if you'd need do do a parseDouble before dividing or not.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti 105/100 = 1, but 105/100.0 = 1.05

Comment: As @JoachimIsaksson said, `int / int = int`. You should brush up and have a read about [Arithmetic Promotion](http://www.codemiles.com/java/arithmetic-promotion-t3487.html).

Comment: That's right, guys, sorry for that. Answer edited.