# Floor issues on specific devices

Tags: android, double, rounding, floor

I have a "rounding" issue, and I would like to understand why I have different results on different devices. Also if anybody knows what is different on these devices that could explain the behavior.

So, I have this code :

```
public final static double round(double val, double interval) {
  return Math.floor(0.5 + (val / interval)) * interval;
}
```

That is returning a value different on the 1st device list and on the 2nd device list

- LG Optimus 2x - Android 2.3.6
- HTC Sensation - Android 2.3.3
- HTC Desire S – Android 2.3.5
- HTC ONE S – Android 4.1.1
- Galaxy Trend – Android 4.0.4
- Mororola RAZR – Android 2.3.5
- Sony Xperia S – Android 2.3.7
- Samsung Galaxy S2 – Android 2.3.6
- Samsung Galaxy Ace – Android 2.3.6
- Nexus 5 – Android 4.4.2
- Galaxy Xcover – Android 2.3.6
- Motorola Defy – Android 2.2.2

2nd list :

- Samsung Google Nexus S – 4.1.1
- Google Galaxy Nexus – 4.2.2
- Nexus 4 – 4.3
- Samsung Galaxy S4 – 4.2.2
- Sony Xperia Z – 4.2.2
- Samsung Galaxy note 2 – 4.1.2
- Samsung S3 – 4.2.2
- Xperia SP – 4.1.2
- Sony Xperia M – 4.1.2
- Sony Xperia E – 4.1.1
- Sony Xperia T – 4.1.2

Comment: what are you actually trying to do with this function? The addition of 0.5 rather than using Math.round() makes me curious...

Comment: also, can you provide at least one example of failing values of val and interval?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places