# How do you shorten a long decimal number in Java?

Tags: java, double, decimal

For example, I have the number 137.99999999999.
How do you format that to one decimal place like 137.9?

Another example would be 4.7777777777 to 4.7

Note: I don't want to round the number at all. I just want to truncate it to one decimal place.

Comment: when you searched, what did you find? I find it hard to believe there aren't many examples online.

Comment: What about `3.19`? Will it become `3.2` or `3.1`?

Comment: I couldn't find anything helpful. I tried looking for it in google and on this website.

Comment: it will become 3.1
No rounding.

Comment: Is is just for printing or do you need it as double?

Comment: It's just for storing it into an array and printing it later.

Comment: sorting is done before truncation or after truncation?

Comment: Truncation of floating point numbers often gives undesirable results. Numbers such as 0.1 cannot be exactly represented, and whether the approximation is slightly big or slightly small varies from number to number. Truncation will take an error in a low significance digit and make it significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) if you need more special approaches as to display 4.77 as 4.7, not as 4.8 (this is [RoundingMode.DOWN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN)):

```
  NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
  format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
  format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  System.out.println(format.format(4.7777));
```

The output is `4.77`

Comment: Can use NumberFormat with RoundingMode.DOWN then.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an elaborate answer here : [Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Tweak it for 1 decimal place and you're good to go.

Or, another simple way to truncate to one decimal point would be :

```
String numberString = "137.99999999999";
int indexOfDecimal = numberString.indexOf('.');
Double truncatedNumber = new Double(numberString.subString(0,indexOfDecimal+2));
```

Comment: There is no constructor in `java.lang.Long` that takes a `double` as an argument.