# double being rounded and not precise

Tags: java, double, precision, rounding

```
double x = 0;
double P = 0.327; //P is a actually function that return double and change all the time
double w1 = 1/4; //prints 0 (w1 and w2 are same as P)
double w2= 10/4; //prints 2
x=x+P*w1+(1-P)*w2; 
System.out.println(x); // prints 1.346 and the real result is 1.76425
```

i dont know how to overcome the problem of double that is rounding down, i tried the BigDecimal, maybe i just dont do it right..

i dont need very precise result but i do need the result 1.764.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1 / 4` and `10 / 4` are integer divisions. Their result is an int, that is then widened to a double. What you want is a double division:

```
double w1 = 1.0 / 4
```

or

```
double w1 = 1 / 4.0
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are performing integer division (1, 4 and 10 are treated as integers, so `1/4` and `1/10` will be integer divisions).

Change `w1` and `w2` to:

```
double w1 = 1/4.0;
double w2 = 10/4.0;
```

This way java will perform floating point division

Answer (score 0):

`setScale` and then use the [**`ROUND_HALF_DOWN`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to rounding down in **bigdecimal**

```
   BigDecimal bigdecimal=new BigDecimal(x);
   bigdecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```