# How to convert a String number to two three decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, string, rounding

I am trying to convert a String number to two decimal places in Java. I saw lot of posts on [satckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places) but somehow I am getting an exception.

```
String number = "1.9040409535344458";
String result = String.format("%.2f", number);

System.out.println(result);
```

This is the exception I am getting -

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
```

I would like to have `1.904` as the output. Does anyone know what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Your number variable is String instead double or float.

Comment: Convert the string to a number and then use the format.

Comment: I  did that also `String.format("%.2f", Integer.parseInt(number));` and this time I am getting an exception as `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.9040409535344458"`

Comment: Because number is not an integer, but a float/double Edit: you should use `Double.parseDouble(number)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `NumberFormat`. For example:

```
String number = "1.9040409535344458";
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000"); 
String result = formatter.format(Double.valueOf(number));

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare number to be double :

```
Double number = 1.9040409535344458;
```

instead of

```
String number = "1.9040409535344458";
```

OUTPUT :

```
1.90
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a format not meant for a `String`.  I would recommend either converting your `String` to a `double` or storing it as a `double` in the first place.  Convert the `String` to a `double`, and pass that `double` to `String.format`.

Answer (score 0):

you should first convert the string into double and then change the decimal value

```
String number = "1.9040409535344458";
double result = Double.parseDouble(number);//converts the string into double
result = result *100;//adjust the decimal value
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Did you try your code snippet? Does it do what the OP wants?