# Java Double Trouble - How can I ensure 4.45 is 4.45 without using BigDecimal?

Tags: java, double, rounding, truncate

So:

```
//aValue = 4.45
//bValue = 4.35
//maxValueDiff = 0.1
//The absolute value of a - b = 0.1

if( Math.abs(aValue - bValue) <= maxValueDiff ) return true;
logger.info("valueDiffCheck a:" + aValue +" b:"+ bValue + " e1:" + maxValueDiff);
```

Why do I see this in my logs:

```
valueDiffCheck a:4.45 b:4.35 e1:0.1
```

Suspect this is because Double is a double pain with it's inaccuracies but if that were the case shouldn't I **see** that? Like it should print that 0.1 is actually 0.10000000111 or something? ...or is there something pesky about the printing format?

The target code is high performance with a LOT of data so we don't want to use BigDecimal. What's the next best thing to ensure that 0.44 is 0.44?

OK let me state unequivocally that we only need two decimal places. The accuracy involved in using BigDecimal is major overkill.

Comment: You would have to use a larger decimal to compare to if you wanted higher precision. Subtraction and addition aren't problems though. You should be more concerned with division if you are worrying about precision issues.

Comment: @Luminous, "Don't know what you mean by "subtraction and addtion aren't problems."  If you write `c = a + b` where a, b, and c are doubles; then it is possible that c is not equal to the real number c' that is the actual sum of a and b.  The difference between c and c' can be as much as 1/2 of one ULP.

Comment: actually, it's printing correctly. What you should print is Math.abs(aValue - bValue)

Comment: Wrote a short unit test and it's the math that causes the inaccuracy. All I need are the two decimal places. The result turns out to be something silly like 0.1000000000000123

Comment: Do not use floating points at all. Instead multiply you input with 1.000.000 and display output appropriately. Six digits as remainder should be enough.

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  This question comes up several times per week on SO.  The simple answer is that it is not possible without using exact decimal arithmetic (i.e. `BigDecimal`).

Comment: @Hannes  Enough for what?  The OP did not tell us what he/she is trying to accomplish.  All we've got is one example.  What do those numbers mean?  If the OP changed the 0.1 to 0.1000000001, that would make the test pass.  Why is 0.1000000001 not acceptable?  Without more information, we don't know.

Comment: Since all we ever do is simple math with values that have only 2 decimals, the solution we used in the end was to multiply by 1000  cast to integer and then do the comparison. It's not accurate but if we needed accuracy we wouldn't be using only two decimal places. ...and no this isn't money. It's the rough length or width of a rock.

Comment: @user447607 Multiplying by 1000 and casting to integer can result in pretty bad rounding errors... `4.3999999` -> `4399.99999` -> `4399` -> `4.399`; you need to have an `ERROR` factor anyway.

Comment: Yes... but we don't care for this application.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by using an error margin in places where it might come up. The following is a very simple way - but not necessarily the best way (you may want it more centralized, configurable, etc.) - to modify your code to do this:

```
private static final double ERROR = 1e-7;

// SNIP

if( Math.abs(aValue - bValue) <= maxValueDiff + ERROR) return true;
logger.info("valueDiffCheck a:" + aValue +" b:"+ bValue + " e1:" + maxValueDiff);
```

Comment: Nice one ... now find all the places to insert this in ;)

Comment: @Drejc The best thing to do is have a method like "DoubleChecker" - you can even use a custom [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) matcher - but all of that is more complicated than the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be exact, I don't see any way around using BigDecimal.

But depending what you do with this numbers you can always round using `Math.round` to "ensure" you have the "correct" decimals set.

[Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: The question as stated was about how to avoid BigDecimal. The provided solution uses BigDecimal. We only need 2 decimal places.

Comment: The solution is to use Math.round if you read the answer ... and the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always consider using your own decimal class that uses `long` to store the value and a decimal placeholder.

```
public Class MyDecimal
{
    private long value = 0;
    private long decimalPlace = 0;

    ...
}
```

This means you can make 0.44 be doing something like:

```
MyDecimal decimal = new MyDecimal(44, 2);
```

As mentioned in the other answer though, `BigDecimal` will be your best bet to ensure accuracy.