# Math round Java issue 2.495 to 2 digits = 2.49

Tags: java, math, rounding, digit

First off this is the code I use :

```
public static float roundAt(float value ,  int digits) {

    double pow = Math.pow(10, digits);
    double retvalue;

    retvalue = (value * pow); 
    retvalue = Math.round(retvalue);
    retvalue = retvalue / pow;

    return (float) retvalue;        
}
```

So using this method I do the following

if I round these values:

```
roundAt(0.495f,2) = 0.5
roundAt(1.495f,2) = 1.5
roundAt(2.495f,2) = 2.49
```

I try to understand the logic behind this but I can't. I want the rounding to act the same everytime so I would get 2.5 with `roundAt(2.495f,2)`. Any idea what's going on ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is, that you calculation...

```
retvalue = (value * pow);
```

...leads to...

```
2.495 * 100.0 = 249.4999885559082
```

Using a double instead of a float will fix that specific problem. Neither float nor double are exact values, but float is even less exact than double and will lead to errors more easily. If you are curious, you will find much material on floating point arithmetics out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `2.495f * 100.0` you will notice that the result is `249.4999885559082`. Since the decimal part is less than `.5`, this gets rounded down to `249.0` that, when divided by `100.0`, gives `2.49`.

If you want more information on how to round a double, check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places).