# Cut down a double number at a certain point after the decimal point

Tags: java, swing

So im having a double and i want my JLabel to display it, i do it like this:

```
   jlabel.setText(String.valueOf(80.99999D)); // just an example number
```

But in addition to that, i would like to cut down the double number to maximum 2 digits behind the decimal point. So in the example above i would like the JLabel to only display 80.99. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by using `String.format`

```
String.format("%.2f", 80.99999);
```

The number after the `.` defines, how many digits are displayed after the period (max). If you write `.02f` you will always have 2 digits after the period.

Comment: String.format would round the number, so: `String.format("%.2f", 80.99999)` would give you `81.00`. If you really don't want to round up, see this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462708/how-do-i-format-double-input-in-java-without-rounding-it?rq=1).