# Round String.ValueOf to nearest whole number

Tags: android, rounding

I'm trying to round a String.ValueOf to the nearest whole number. Any idea how to get String.valueOf(result) to the nearest whole number.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       double result =0;
       double result1 =0; 
       double a = Double.parseDouble(weightEntered.getText().toString().trim());
       double b = 2.2;
    if(v == button_convert)
    {
        if(lbs_kg.isChecked() == true) {
            result = (a / b);
            String str = String.valueOf(result);
            t1.setText(str);
        }
```

Comment: Math.round(String.valueOf(result)) should do :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Think about that for a second.

Comment: see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I tried that already but it says cannot resolve method 'round'(java.land.string)

Comment: @user3091082 see the full post, the round function body is also in the post which you should also copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = String.valueOf(Math.round(result));
```