# In Junit testing, how to comparing two ArrayList<Double> using assertEquals(), and is there an better alternative?

Tags: java, unit-testing, arraylist, junit, double

I'm currently writing a Junit test where I use `assertEquals()` to compare the value of two `ArrayList<Double>`.

```
@Test
public void test(){

        QuadraticFormula one = new QuadraticFormula(3, 4, -4);
        List<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.add(0.66666);
        results.add(-2.0);

        assertEquals(results, one.getRoots());
    }
```

However, Junit prints out the following failure message:

```
expected:<[0.66666, -2.0]> but was:<[0.6666666666666666, -2.0]>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
```

Is there anyway I can specify how many decimal places I want the test to compare? I know how to test equality of two double values to certain accuracy, but is there anyway that this can be achieved when comparing two ArrayList of doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NumberFormat` or `BigDecimal`

Below will round-of

```
    double d = 0.66666666;
    NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(format.format(d)); // 0.67
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal); // 0.67
```

If you don't want to round-of

```
    double d = 0.66666666;
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(format.format(d)); // 0.66
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(bigDecimal); //0.66
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use BigDecimal instead of Double.

check this SO for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)