# round a double to closest next number

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

I want to round of a double value to the immediate next number.

Tried working with `Math.ceil` and `Math.round` but it didnt help.

Below is the condition and code:

```
Double totalAsset = Util.convertToDouble(dataObject) * calculus;

// 62072560. * 06433535204605706 = 399345.99999999994

System.out.println(totalAsset.longValue());
```

But i get `399345` whereas it should be `399346`.

Comment: Define "the rest" please.

Comment: rest means when we have the decimal starting from 5. it should round off

Comment: No, that still might not be clear to everyone.  Please show a series of numbers and how you want them to round.

Comment: For Eg: A number being 399345.5, 399345.6,399345.7,399345.8,399345.9 should round off to immediate next number.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, that `1.899999` should "round" to `1` and `1.9` should round to `2`? In other words, if the fractional part is less than `0.9` then round down, otherwise round up? If so, try `int(x+0.1)` for positive numbers. Due to the non-exactness of `0.1` in floating point this will rarely be off but it would work almost always.

Comment: 1.899999 should round of to 1.9

Comment: So you want to round normally to the first decimal?

Comment: Yes @Madmenyo rite

Comment: That's what `Math.round` does.  In what way did it fail to work for you?

Comment: Math.round was returning 399346 even for 399345.4

Comment: `06433535204605706` is integer

Comment: refer to [Math.round(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)). _Returns:
the value of the argument rounded to the nearest long value._

Comment: @sTg Really?  I just tested `System.out.println(Math.round(399345.4));` and it printed `399345`.

Comment: @sTg Try to describe what you want/need better to avoid clutter and answers your not looking for. Test things in the simplest way possible first before you make incorrect statements. The 3th comment by Tim is asking for a list of numbers with values you want them to round too, that would have made things easy. Now this whole page is a giant mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print, and thus not lose any precision you can use `DecimalFormat`.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
double d = 1.899999;
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Otherwise, precise rounding of a double has some strings attached to it. I advise reading the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/1322271) which I ripped this method from:

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
  if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
  bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

If you do want to ceil your numbers, which is still unclear to me you can change the `RoundingMode` to `RoundingMode.CEILING`. Read more about RoundingMode [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? 
Each `println()` statement prints 399346.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final long l0 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.1); //Becomes 399346
        final long l1 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.5); //Becomes 399346
        final long l2 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.6); //Becomes 399346
        final long l3 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.7); //Becomes 399346
        final long l4 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.8); //Becomes 399346
        final long l5 = (long) Math.ceil(399345.9); //Becomes 399346

        System.out.println(l0); //Prints 399346
        System.out.println(l1); //Prints 399346
        System.out.println(l2); //Prints 399346
        System.out.println(l3); //Prints 399346
        System.out.println(l4); //Prints 399346
        System.out.println(l5); //Prints 399346
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could adding an If-statement help?

Substract the real result (1234,56) with the shortened one (1234) and check if the result is >= 0,5 to round up or < 0,5 to round down?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the overhead, than `BigDecimal` comes to your rescue:

```
final BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1.899999");
final BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1.911111");
System.out.println(a.setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP)); // prints 1.9
System.out.println(b.setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP)); // prints 2.0
```