# Java Android precision loss when adding Doubles

Tags: java, android

When I run this code:

```
  Double test = (23.1d + 0.1d);
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Test: " + test);
```

I get:

```
 Test: 23.200000000000003
```

I need to add values that will at most have two decimals. For example 19.99 + 0.1 =20.09, how can I do it so that precision is not lost?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places I believe this will be helpful foryou.

Answer (score 0):

double i2=i/60000;

tv.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(i2));

> use this code