# How get format decimal 1 place in Android

Tags: java, android

Hi how i can to get a decimal with place?, for example 9.924kms by 9.9kms

My code is

```
td = String.valueOf(totalDistance / 1000.0);
```

Comment: use decimal format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 DecimalFormat format= new DecimalFormat("#.0");
 td = format.format(totalDistance / 1000.0);
```

Or refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/8867002) which is for rounding numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat`. You can also set `RoundingMode` to get the ceiling for last digit . Below is an example .

```
 double x=2.7883;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
 System.out.println(df.format(x));
```

Output:- 2.8

For setting mode you can use .

```
 df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
```

Comment: Beware of `.#`, [it won't print the decimal number if it'll be 0](https://ideone.com/Ka5JvF)... you need `.0` to always have one decimal number (more on http://www.baeldung.com/java-decimalformat)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying