# Code Runs but it is saying wrong answer and cant move on with message I don't understand

Tags: java

I have this assignment and I am about to throw this laptop. The following code runs, but when I test it in MindTap I get the bottom message. I don't know what I am doing wrong or why it says incorrect.

Assignment:
Write three overloaded computeBill methods for a photo book store:

When computeBill receives a single parameter, it represents the price of one photo book ordered. Add 8% tax, and return the total due.
When computeBill receives two parameters, they represent the price of a photo book and the quantity ordered. Multiply the two values, add 8% tax, and return the total due.
When computeBill receives three parameters, they represent the price of a photo book, the quantity ordered, and a coupon value. Multiply the quantity and price, reduce the result by the coupon value, and then add 8% tax and return the total due.

My Coding:enter code here
    public class Billing {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   double yourTotal;
    yourTotal = computeBill(31.00);
    displayTotal (yourTotal);
    yourTotal = computeBill (31, 2);
    displayTotal(yourTotal);
    yourTotal = computeBill(31, 2, .2); 
    displayTotal (yourTotal);
 }
 public static double computeBill (double price) 
{double total = price * 1.08;
 System.out.println ("You ordered 1 photobook for $" + price);
 System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");
 return total;}

public static double computeBill (double price, int qty) {
double subtotal = price * qty;
double total = subtotal * 1.08;
 System.out.println ("You ordered" + qty + " photobook(s) for $" + price);
 System.out.println("Subtotal =" + subtotal);
System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");
return total;
 }

public static double computeBill (double price, int qty, double discount) {
double subtotal = price * qty;
 subtotal = subtotal - (subtotal * discount);    
 double total = subtotal * 1.08;
  System.out.println ("You ordered " + qty + " photobook(s) for $" + price);
  System.out.println("Subtotal = " + subtotal);
  System.out.println("Less your " + (discount * 100) + "% discount"); 
System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");   
return total;
}
public static void displayTotal (double total){
    System.out.println("Total: $" + total);
  }
  }
```

Result MindTap gives me when I test:
Build Status
Build Succeeded
Test Output
You ordered2 photobook(s) for $31.0
Subtotal =62.0
Plus sales tax 8%
[FAILED]: unitTest(CodevolveTest12f618f0): null
false
Test Contents
    Billing tester30 = new Billing();

```
@Test
public void unitTest() {
assertTrue(tester30.computeBill(31, 2) == 66.96);
```

}

Someone please help me. I am sooooo stuck!!!`

Comment: Debug it. 1. Begin commenting out code until the error goes away or you see the problem. 2. Use the symbolic debugger that you got for free in your IDE.

Comment: When I run your `computeBill` method, it's actually returning `66.96000000000001`, so you might be a victim of some floating point issue

Comment: You're probably going to want to look at [Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places) and [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java), but personally, I found `new BigDecimal(total).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();` to be more elegant

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the digits after decimal so that comparison becomes logical as:

```
public static double computeBill (double price, int qty) {
        double subtotal = price * qty;
        double total = subtotal * 1.08;
        System.out.println ("You ordered" + qty + " photobook(s) for $" + price);
        System.out.println("Subtotal =" + subtotal);
        System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");

        // need to limit to two digit after decimal
        return Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(total));
}
```

So, you test:

```
@Test
public void unitTest() {
     assertTrue(tester30.computeBill(31, 2) == 66.96); // comparing two digits after decimal 
}
```

Comment: public static double computeBill (double price, int qty) {
    double subtotal = price * qty;
    double total = subtotal * 1.08;
   System.out.println ("You ordered" + qty + " photobook(s) for $" + price);
  System.out.println("Subtotal =" + subtotal);
    System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");
   return Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(total));
}

Comment: public static double computeBill (double price, int qty) {
    double subtotal = price * qty;
    double total = subtotal * 1.08;
   System.out.println ("You ordered" + qty + " photobook(s) for $" + price);
  System.out.println("Subtotal =" + subtotal);
    System.out.println("Plus sales tax 8%");
   return Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(total));
}   gives me an error that says: Billing.java:24: error: return Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(total));       symbol: class Decimal    location: class Billing     so its still wrong. now confused!!!

Comment: @crystalgurley did you import `import java.text.DecimalFormat;`??

Comment: @crystalgurley i have working code on github https://github.com/YogenRaii/java-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eprogrammerz/examples/careercup/Billing.java

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I still had to do couple of edits because my discount was not calculating correct. Finally finished with that one! :)

Comment: @crystalgurley good to hear :) .. would you mind upvoting/accepting answer? ;)