# Round a double to 2 decimal places displaying "#.00" instead of "#.0"

Tags: java, floating-point, double, decimal, rounding

My Android app (Java code) is displaying for example `15.0` and the format that I need to display is `15.00`. My variable is `double`. How can I achieve that? What I have tried is the following code from Jonik's answer at [Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places):

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Then I use this:

```
double myValue = 15.0;
round(myValue, 2);
System.out.println(myValue);
```

I wanted to see `15.00` printed out. However, what I see is `15.0` and that is not what I want. Any ideas to achieve what I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). Something like this should work:

```
double a = 10.19823493;
double b = 1.2;

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

System.out.println(formatter.format(a)); // "10.20"
System.out.println(formatter.format(b)); // "1.20"
```