# Event Listener to Performing Arithmetic Operations on TextFields

Tags: java, listener, textfield, event-listener

I'm getting confused with execution on a block of code. I have 4 textfields each being `quantity`, `price`, `vat` and `amount`.

I want to add an event listener to `price` and `quantity` textfields so that whenever I change the text in each, the new `vat` calculation and new `amount` values are automatically shown in their respective textfields.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
    private void addEventListeners() {
        txtInvoiceQuantity.textProperty().addListener((ChangeListener) (observable, oldVal, newVal) -> calculateVATAmount((String) oldVal, (String) newVal));
    }

    private void calculateVATAmount(String oldVal, String newVal) {
 if (newVal.length() > oldVal.length()) {
            if (txtInvoiceQuantity.getText().length() > 0 && txtInvoicePrice.getText().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(newVal);
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(txtInvoicePrice.getText());
                    double vat = Double.parseDouble(lblVAT.getText()) / 100;
                    double vatamount = quantity * price * vat;
                    txtInvoiceVAT.setText(String.valueOf(vatamount));
                    double invoiceAmount = (price * quantity) + vatamount;
                    txtInvoiceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceAmount));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I obviously can't use that event as it is on `txtInvoiceQuantity`. So how can I change `calculateVATAmount(oldVal,newVal)` so that it does what I want it to do?

How do I also factor in the oldVal (in case a user presses back space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to my understanding, you would have to duplicate that block of code since you're passing in parameters from different textfields in each handler.

As for factoring in the old value, just remove the `if(newVal.length() > oldVal.length()) {}` . It should look like this:

```
   private void quantityHandler(String oldVal, String newVal) {
            if (txtInvoiceQuantity.getText().length() > 0 && txtInvoicePrice.getText().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(newVal);
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(txtInvoicePrice.getText());
                    double vat = Double.parseDouble(lblVAT.getText()) / 100;
                    double vatamount = quantity * price * vat;
                    txtInvoiceVAT.setText(String.valueOf(round(vatamount,2)));
                    double invoiceAmount = (price * quantity) + vatamount;
                    txtInvoiceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(round(invoiceAmount,2)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
    private void priceHandler(String oldVal, String newVal) {
            if (txtInvoiceQuantity.getText().length() > 0 && txtInvoicePrice.getText().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(txtInvoiceQuantity.getText());
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(newVal);
                    double vat = Double.parseDouble(lblVAT.getText()) / 100;
                    double vatamount = quantity * price * vat;
                    txtInvoiceVAT.setText(String.valueOf(round(vatamount,2)));
                    double invoiceAmount = (price * quantity) + vatamount;
                    txtInvoiceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(round(invoiceAmount,2)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

Since you're working with monetary values, I found a method that converts to a specified number of decimal places, find it here

[Rounding to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for