# Android double serialization issue

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor-client

I have an API who return this data

```
 {
  "QUANTITYKG": 19.044,
  "QUANTITYPC": 6.0,
  "QUANTITYM": 36.0,
  "QUANTITYM2": 0.0,
 }
```

In my android project I have a data class to handle the API Response.

```
@Serializable
data class Data(
    @SerialName("QUANTITYKG")
    val quantityKg: Double,
    @SerialName("QUANTITYPC")
    val quantityPc: Double,
    @SerialName("QUANTITYM")
    val quantityM: Double,
    @SerialName("QUANTITYM2")
    val quantityM2: Double

) {
```

When I received the response on my Application instead of 19.044 for the QUANTITYKG I received 19.04.

I try many solutions like format the response,  but nothing is working. Can you help me to find the issue please. Thank you !!

Comment: Firstly, I recommend using BigDecimal. [Here's a thread that might help explain why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808648/21612640).

Even despite this, this plainly should not be the case based on what we have to work with. You are probably observing the value to two decimal places, not three. Use `String.format("%.3f", x)` where `x` is your value, and print the result, it should show three decimal places.

Comment: Receiving all the data in string format then converting them to number will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This will never be 19.04, because 19.04 is not a valid floating point number.  Valid floating point numbers are sums of powers of 2-   1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc.  .04 is not exactly represented in this.  So the problem is in whatever code you were using to display it, not in the conversion itself.