# Strange behavior when rounding floating point numbers in Java

Tags: java, rounding

I need to implement a small metric converter class which has the main task to convert metrics. For example convert meters to miles.
An additional acceptance criteria is to round the results with one digit accuracy except if the number is less than 0.1, then it should be rounded to 2 digits of accuracy.

I have programmed for rounding following method:

```
public static String round(double input) {
        DecimalFormat df;

        if(input < 0.1) {
            df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        } else {
            df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        }

        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(currentLocale));

        return df.format(input);
    }
```

Now i wrote some unit tests in order to validate the code.

```
package de.helper;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;

import java.util.Locale;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


class MetricsConverterTest {

    @Test
    public void roundNumberWith1DigitAccuracy() {

        //arrange
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

        //act
        String actualRoundDown = MetricsConverter.round(10.123456);
        String actualRoundUp = MetricsConverter.round(10.153456);

        //assert
        assertThat(actualRoundDown).isEqualTo("10,1");
        assertThat(actualRoundUp).isEqualTo("10,2");
    }

    @Test
    public void roundSmallNumberWith2DigitAccuracy() {

        //arrange
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

        //act
        String actualRoundDown = MetricsConverter.round(0.091);
        String actualRoundUp = MetricsConverter.round(0.076);

        //assert
        assertThat(actualRoundDown).isEqualTo("0,09");
        assertThat(actualRoundUp).isEqualTo("0,08");

    }

    @Test
    public void roundSmallNumberWith2DigitAccuracyStrangeEdgeCase() {

        //arrange
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

        //act
        String actualRoundUp = MetricsConverter.round(0.075);

        //assert
        assertThat(actualRoundUp).isEqualTo("0,08");
    }

    @Test
    public void roundSmallNumberEdgeCase1DigitAccuracy() {

        //arrange
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

        //act
        String actualRoundUp = MetricsConverter.round(0.095);

        //assert
        assertThat(actualRoundUp).isEqualTo("0,1");
    }
}
```

But the test method `roundSmallNumberWith2DigitAccuracyStrangeEdgeCase` fails. The actual output is "0.07" but for my understanding it should be 0.08. What do I miss?

Comment: check [Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2808535/85421) (and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Brounding%5D+double) on this site)

Comment: Side note: the entire method can be simplified to `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( input < 0.1? "#.##": "#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance( LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP); return df.format(input);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `0.075` cannot be represented by a `double` with absolute precision. You can see that if you print the value of `new BigDecimal(0.075)`:

```
0.07499999999999999722444243843710864894092082977294921875
```

That number is definitely closer to 0.07 than it is to 0.08, hence you get the result that you see.

Answer (score 1):

You can't due to `double` being an imprecise representation of a number.

However, you can make it work if you use a precise representation. Use `BigDecimal` and first round it to two places:

```
public static String round(double input) {
    BigDecimal n = BigDecimal.valueOf(input).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // will be 0.75
    // your code here
}
```

Since you're learning, I've left the rest of the implementation up to you to complete.

Comment: Whether BigDecimal is appropriate for this task or not depends on the source of the input. If the input is human-generated, and the user expects "0.075" to be as precise as it's written, then BigDecimal is appropriate. If it comes from a digital measuring instrument, such as a USB thermometer, then you should use `double`. The BigDecimal type is only appropriate for _decimal_ representations. It is a fallacy to think that BigDecimal is precise. It's not. It can't represent all real values precisely.

Comment: @k314159 sorry, typo. I started with a `String` parameter, but realised this approach works with `double` too, but forgot to change the parameter type. Fixed now. Regarding precision, BigDecimal isn't absolutely precise, but is precise *enough* for this use case.

Comment: Yes, I see. We just need to make sure we use `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.075)` gives 0.075, and not `new BigDecimal(0.075)` which gives 0.074999....

Comment: @k314159 `.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` does just that

Comment: No, it's not `setScale` that does it. It's `valueOf`. If you didn't use `valueOf`, and you used `new BigDecimal(double)` instead, then it wouldn't work. `new BigDecimal(0.075).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)` gives 0.07 instead of 0.08.