# Round a decimal to the nearest quarter in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

Is there a simple way in c# to round a decimal to the nearest quarter i.e. x.0, x.25, x.50 x.75
for example 0.21 would round to 0.25, 5.03 would round to 5.0

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Multiply it by four, [round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx) it as you need to an integer, then divide it by four again:

```
x = Math.Round (x * 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4;
```

The various options for rounding, and their explanations, can be found in this excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252) :-)

Comment: I wrote this answer as [an extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443473/569302):

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you can use UltimateRoundingFunction given in this blog:
http://rajputyh.blogspot.in/2014/09/the-ultimate-rounding-function.html

> ```
> //amountToRound => input amount
> //nearestOf => .25 if round to quater, 0.01 for rounding to 1 cent, 1 for rounding to $1
> //fairness => btween 0 to 0.9999999___.
> //            0 means floor and 0.99999... means ceiling. But for ceiling, I would recommend, Math.Ceiling
> //            0.5 = Standard Rounding function. It will round up the border case. i.e. 1.5 to 2 and not 1.
> //            0.4999999... non-standard rounding function. Where border case is rounded down. i.e. 1.5 to 1 and not 2.
> //            0.75 means first 75% values will be rounded down, rest 25% value will be rounded up.
> decimal UltimateRoundingFunction(decimal amountToRound, decimal nearstOf, decimal fairness)
> {
>     return Math.Floor(amountToRound / nearstOf + fairness) * nearstOf;
> }
> ```

Call below for standard rounding. i.e. 1.125 will be rounded to 1.25

```
UltimateRoundingFunction(amountToRound, 0.25m, 0.5m);
```

Call below for rounding down border values. i.e. 1.125 will be rounded to 1.00

```
UltimateRoundingFunction(amountToRound, 0.25m, 0.4999999999999999m);
```

So called "Banker's Rounding" is not possible with UltimateRoundingFunction, you have to go with paxdiablo's answer for that support :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to round to the nearest n.

Answer (score 0):

Notice: This isn't a thing you do in a script.

If you have something like this:

```
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(
    x: Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) + direction.x,
    y: Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.y) + direction.y,
    z: 0.0f
    );
```

Then go to Unity > Project Settings > Time
And then you can change the time.

Answer (score -1):

An extension method based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826278).

```
namespace j
{
    public static class MathHelpers
    {
        public static decimal RoundToNearestQuarter(this decimal x)
        {
            return Math.Round(x * 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4;
        }
    }
}
```