# C# how to always round down to nearest 50

Tags: c#, function, math, decimal, rounding

I've done a search on C# rounding, but haven't been able to find the answer to my current problem.

What I want to do is always round down to the nearest 50. All the values I want to round down will be in decimal.

So 635.25 would be 600.

298.42 would be 250.

149.56 would be 100.

I've looked at math.round but how would I use that so it always rounds down to the nearest 50 and never up?

Comment: This is a very popular question. One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro: Given programming languages handle this differently (maybe not with this example, but in the presence of a negative number), I would have to disagree.

Comment: I kept finding ones that would round up and down and not just down, missed that, thanks

Comment: @leppie Agreed.This is why I said it is "more of a math question", not "definitely a math question"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Divide the value by 50, round down to the closest whole number, and multiply by 50 again:

```
double n = Math.Floor(n / 50.0) * 50.0;
```

Comment: Did not notice the never round up +1 :)

Comment: Oh well, added an alternative ;) Might be cheaper if you are into micro optimizations ;p

Comment: As in my case, if you need to round the number up to the next 50 use Math.Ceiling().

Answer (score 5):

Another way to Guffa's:

```
(((int) value) / 50) * 50
```

Comment: This is not the same as Guffa's answer. Negative numbers are rounded up here.

Comment: @Jens: Given positive numbers, it is the same :)

Answer (score 4):

Using modulus:

```
var roundedDownToClosestFifty = value - (value % 50);
```