# Rounding to nearest truncated 100

Tags: c#

I want to know how I could round to the nearest 100, when a value is truncated. 
I was using this:

```
private static int CalculatePaperLevel(int paperLevel)
{
   int roundedLevel = 0;
   roundedLevel = ((int)Math.Round(paperLevel / 10.0) * 10);
   return roundedLevel;
}
```

but this, is what I want

E.G. 
191 -> 100

224 -> 200

140 -> 100

295 -> 200

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15028144/62576

Answer (score 9):

You could just do `roundedLevel = (paperLevel / 100) * 100;`

This works because integer arithmetic always truncates results to integers. So

- (295 / 100) -> 2
- 2 * 100 -> 200

Answer (score 2):

Truncation like this is what happens when you divide two `int`s in C#. This code does what you want:

```
private static int CalculatePaperLevel(int paperLevel)
{
   int roundedLevel = paperLevel / 100 * 100;
   return roundedLevel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't quite sure what "truncation" was, exactly and that makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the function you want is called [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Math.Floor (37D/100)*100`

Comment: The argument `37/100` has type `int`. Why use floor function on an `int`?

Comment: @Jeppe It will be handled as decimal since Floor only accepts decimal and double

Comment: The division will return an `int` since the overload one could describe as `int operator /(int, int)` (defined by C# spec, not necessarily a real .NET method) is clearly the best overload of `/` here. Then the overload of `Floor` to use would be hard to choose. Does this compile? _Edit:_ Ah, you changed it.