# Round decimal to nearest 50 and return integer

Tags: c#

A follow on from this question:
[C# how to always round down to nearest 50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028144/c-sharp-how-to-always-round-down-to-nearest-50)

How would I round a decimal to the nearest 50 and return an int, I could do the following but there must be a more efficent solution?

```
decimal test = 154.45m;
decimal newValue = Math.Floor(test / 50m) * 50.0m;
int testInt = Convert.ToInt32(newValue);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of converting to `int`, you can just get the `int` part by casting.

```
int testInt = (int) Math.Floor(test / 50m) * 50.0m;
```

I am not sure how much performance you would gain by this, but [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93kx4xke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would also do the rounding to nearest 32 bit integer, whereas casting would just give you the `int` part

Comment: should of guessed this really, obviously my brain is not working, thanks.

Comment: int testInt = test-(test%50); to avoid function call?