# Rounding float decimals to set resolution

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, rounding

I have an animation timeline of sorts that has a resolution set which is a factor of 1 second.

> A resolution of 4 is (1000/4) which means that events are called
>   every .25 .5 and .75th of a second.

I need a way to round the decimals of floats that the user enters to the set resolution so that my timeline events can only start and end on numbers from the resolution.

> With a resolution of 4, 1.20 would round up to 1.25, 4.85 would be
>   rounded down to 4.75, and 2.5 wouldn't be rounded

What is the simplest way to do this using the given the float in question and the resolution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329426/how-do-i-round-to-the-nearest-0-5  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scale your values by your "resolution", round to nearest integer, then scale it back, like this:

```
double originalValue = 1.2;
double resolution = 4;
double roundedValue;

roundedValue = Math.Round(originalValue * resolution, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / resolution; // 1.25
```

The `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` option is needed to get *.5 rounded "up" (i.e. away from zero).

Comment: You may want to use `Math.Round(originalValue * resolution, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` as the default is `MidpointRounding.ToEven`.