# C# round off to specific values

Tags: c#

How would I go about round off floats ONLY to multiples of 0.025

So for example: 1.041 would be rounded off to 1.05

I know how to round off floats in C# but only to decimal values.

Comment: i want to upvote cos its an interesting challenge, but downvote because you havent tried anyting

Comment: multiply by 400 and put the result in an int. now place that in a float and divice by 400

Comment: Here's a question/answer that is very similar to what you're asking here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp

Comment: @pm100 I didn't even know where to start trying :(. I have a book on C# by John Sharp and looked online but could not find anything even remotely useful.

Comment: @beska Thank you. That makes sense. I had looked into Math.round but it didn't seem useful because I didn't know about MidpointRounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp)

```
public static float QuarterTenthsRound(this float number)
{
     var decimalPlaces = number - (int)number;

     float wholeNumber = (float)((Math.Round((decimalPlaces * 10) * 4, 
           MidpointRounding.ToEven) / 4) / 10);            

     return (int)number + wholeNumber;
}
```

I used it as an extension method, so `myFloat.QuarterTenthsRound()` would be the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

```
public static decimal Round(decimal value)
{
    var ceiling = Math.Ceiling(value * 400);

    return ceiling / 400;
}
```

Comment: Why the `if`? It would return `0` in that case anyways.

Comment: @DStanley Good Call, I pulled it from another function I was using

Comment: you stole my algorithm :-)

Comment: Thank you for the solution @bumble_bee_tuna Gave it an upvote but since I'm a newbie won't count until I hit 15 reputation :(

Comment: @JJHarris If the answer helped you please mark it as answered