# Round DOWN to quarter (0.25)

Tags: c#

If I have a `double`, and want to round it down to the nearest quarter value (0.25), is this possible?

Each of these give me 0.5 and should actually give me 0.25:

```
Math.Round(0.499999, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Math.Round(0.499999, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

Is there any notion of always rounding "down"?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp) is related to "nearest" rounding. I don't need that

The "duplicate" is entirely based on NEAREST rounding. that is utterly irrelevant to me. I am not asking about NEAREST. I am asking about always rounding DOWN. Notice that 0.499999 is very NEAR to 0.5 - and that is not what I want. I want 0.49999 to become 0.25 (DOWN)

Comment: @stuartd the question is clear; "round _down_ to nearest quarter".

Comment: @AlexMcMillan you're quite right, thanks

Comment: Do you need to handle negative numbers?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan - yes, actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double x = 0.4999;
double answer = Math.Truncate(4*x)/4; // result: 0.25
```

Comment: This worked (with negatives too), thanks!