# C# round float to the next quarter (0.25)

Tags: c#, .net

I need to round a decimal to the next quarter for example:

```
0.21 to 0.25
0.42 to 0.5
0.63 to 0.75
0.90 to 1
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: And what would 0.10 round to? Would that round to 0.25, or down to 0? (*All* of the examples you've given would naturally round up, which doesn't help us know what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a decimal to the nearest quarter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "multiply by four; round to the nearest integer (built in); divide by four"?

Comment: float x = 0.63f;    x =(float)(Math.Ceiling(x / 0.25) * 0.25);   //0.75