# Limiting double to 3 decimal places

Tags: c#, double, truncate

This i what I am trying to achieve:

If a double has more than 3 decimal places, I want to truncate any decimal places beyond the third. (do not round.)

```
Eg.: 12.878999 -> 12.878
```

If a double has less than 3 decimals, leave unchanged

```
Eg.:   125   -> 125
       89.24 -> 89.24
```

I came across this command:

```
double example = 12.34567;
double output = Math.Round(example, 3);
```

But I do not want to round. According to the command posted above, 
`12.34567 -> 12.346`

I want to truncate the value so that it becomes: `12.345`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797342/how-do-i-round-down-a-decimal-to-2-decimal-places-in-net

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Doubles don't have decimal places - they're not based on decimal digits to start with. You could get "the closest double to the current value when truncated to three decimal digits", but it still wouldn't be exactly the same. You'd be better off using `decimal`.

Having said that, if it's only the way that rounding happens that's a problem, you can use `Math.Truncate(value * 1000) / 1000;` which *may* do what you want. (You don't want *rounding* at all, by the sounds of it.) It's still potentially "dodgy" though, as the result still won't really just have three decimal places. If you did the same thing with a decimal value, however, it *would* work:

```
decimal m = 12.878999m;
m = Math.Truncate(m * 1000m) / 1000m;
Console.WriteLine(m); // 12.878
```

EDIT: As LBushkin pointed out, you should be clear between truncating for *display* purposes (which can usually be done in a format specifier) and truncating for further calculations (in which case the above should work).

Comment: If the "truncation" is only for display purposes, that can be achieved when the value is converted to a string representation. This would preserve precision and avoid some of the pitfalls of trying to perform precise decimal manipulation of a floating point number.

Comment: @LBushkin: True. It depends on what's required. Sometimes businesses really want calculations to be performed on truncated values at each point... and sometimes it's only for display. Good to point out.

Comment: @JonSkeet by default it is truncating to 3 decimal places?

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: Nope - I'm not sure why you'd think that.

Comment: your snippet has no where specified so it made m think'

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: It's multiplying by 1000, truncating to an integer and dividing by 1000. If those were 10000m instead, it would be to 4 decimal places.

Comment: for showing specific number percision, this is the recommended way? :http://stackoverflow.com/a/3814295/1875256

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: For *display* purposes, yes, that's fine.

Comment: Your statement is wrong, a double has decimal its a floating point type double ±5.0e−324 to ±1.7e308 15-16 digits

Comment: @user3800527: I think you should read the whole answer. A double is a sign, mantissa and exponent, where the exponent indicates the *binary* shift; it doesn't have *decimal* digits. Yes, that number can be represented in decimal, but that's not inherent data in the value.

Answer (score 56):

I can't think of a reason to explicitly lose precision outside of display purposes. In that case, simply use string formatting.

```
double example = 12.34567;

Console.Out.WriteLine(example.ToString("#.000"));
```

Comment: I need it because I am matching values from an XML file against those stored in a DB. Both sources are filled in by different parties. The one that fills in the Db chooses not to fill in anything more than 3 decimal places, while the XML file can often have upto 8 decimal places

Comment: @StevenSudit And another possible use-case, like mine, is where I have a DB field that can only take 10 chars, but the form has a lb -> kg field where a calculation takes place and can give a number > 10 chars.  Sometimes you just want a few significant digits and don't want to truncate or round, but have limitations on how many figures out that you can store.  So I would downvote questioning this use-case, as it is very common when storing numbers in a DB field, not upvote it. Luckily it has a useful answer, so I'll upvote, instead.

Comment: ToString rounds the number!

Answer (score 26):

```
double example = 3.1416789645;
double output = Convert.ToDouble(example.ToString("N3"));
```

Comment: I needed to only some decimal places after example.This helped.:)

Answer (score 7):

Multiply by 1000 then use [Truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx) then divide by 1000.

Comment: Yes you're right. Same method, but the double overload as opposed to decimal.

Answer (score 6):

If your purpose in truncating the digits is for display reasons, then you just just use an appropriate formatting when you convert the double to a string.

Methods like `String.Format()` and `Console.WriteLine()` (and others) allow you to limit the number of digits of precision a value is formatted with.

**Attempting to "truncate" floating point numbers is ill advised** -  floating point numbers don't have a precise decimal representation in many cases. Applying an approach like scaling the number up, truncating it, and then scaling it down could easily change the value to something quite different from what you'd expected for the "truncated" value.

**If you need precise decimal representations of a number you should be using `decimal` rather than `double` or `float`.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
double example = 12.34567;
double output = ( (double) ( (int) (example * 1000.0) ) ) / 1000.0 ;
```

Comment: My only concern here is that conversion to int not only slices the digits after the decimal place but restricts the range of the value to what an int can contain. A double can be much bigger than an int.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers above- if you're looking for something reusable here is the code. Note that you might want to check the decimal places value, and this may overflow.

```
public static decimal TruncateToDecimalPlace(this decimal numberToTruncate, int decimalPlaces)
{
    decimal power = (decimal)(Math.Pow(10.0, (double)decimalPlaces));

    return Math.Truncate((power * numberToTruncate)) / power;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C lang:

```
double truncKeepDecimalPlaces(double value, int numDecimals)
{
    int x = pow(10, numDecimals);
    return (double)trunc(value * x) / x;
}
```