# Restricting the number of digits after decimal

Tags: c#, string-formatting

For the purpose of limiting the number of digits after the decimal, I am doing the following in my webpage.

```
Single nnuma = Convert.ToSingle(dr["num1"].ToString());
Single numb = Convert.ToSingle(dr["num2"].ToString());
```

I have to restrict the number of digits after decimal to 3. How is this done here in Single data type?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814190/limiting-double-to-3-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. This will also properly precision the last digit, ie 0.6666 will be 0.667

```
decimal num = 20.123456789m;
Single x = Convert.ToSingle(String.Format("{0:00.000}", num));
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this 
nnuma.ToString ("#.###");
numb.ToString ("#.###");

Comment: i got some weird results trying this.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are looking for is [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx):

```
Single unrounded = (Single)dr["num1"];  // change if the DB type is not a single
double rounded = Math.Round(unrounded, 3);
Single roundedSingle = (Single)rounded;
```

`Math.Round` returns a double when used with a Single, hence the need to convert to Single (float) afterwards. As a side note: You might want to consider using `decimal`s as an alternative, if decimal precision is an issue.

Note that this overload of `Math.Round` performs [*Banker's Rounding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), i.e., `0.0005` becomes `0.000`, but `0.0015` becomes `0.002`. If you want a different kind of rounding, use the [Math.Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding) overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. Just Write **#** to Restrict digits after Decimal.

num.ToString("0.0000#") -- Restrict to 4 digits;

num.ToString("0.0#")-- Restrict to 1 digit;

Answer (score -1):

regex is always the answer ;)

```
var n = Regex.Replace(convertedToSingle.ToString(), @"([^.]*\.\d{0,3}).*", "$1");
```

Comment: apparently the wink is not enough for some people. (this does actually work, and isn't the worst way to process a string)