# How to limit the no of character displayed in double in C#?

Tags: c#, double

I want to limit the no of numbers shown in the below program. I get the result as 3.33333333333333E+15

But I want to display **result** variable as 3.333E+15 to match exactly as used in excel sheet.

Is there any other ways? i tried Math.Round also but its not fulfilling my requirement.

```
if (double.TryParse(value, out res))  //value=3333333333333333
{
    double result = Math.Truncate(res*100/100);  //result=3.33333333333333E+15
}
```

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: "Display" would mean it is a string.

Comment: @Deepak: don't confuse value with display

Comment: Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814190/limiting-double-to-3-decimal-places)

Comment: No number is shown in the program above. Have you tried to show it somehow? Show us this code instead

Comment: i want to display as a string

Comment: @Mitch Wheat sorry for mess actually i am using **result** many times for validations and finally only i am converting it to string and displaying, now solved. Thanks for editing the question

Comment: is there another way to store 3.333E+15 directly in to the double result variable. I saw many tutorials but i can format into string only, actually can we able to change the format of decimal while parsing it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For display purposes you usually tend to use [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case the format string `G4` would match your desired output format. Don't mangle the values themselves to fit your format. Especially with binary floating-point that's prone to failure anyway. E.g. you could round off trailing digits only to have your number appear as `3.3330000002e15`.

Note that depending on how you convert the value to a string, usage of the above-mentioned `G4` differs:

```
var s = d.ToString("G4");
var s2 = string.Format("Value: {0:G4}", d);
```

Comment: is there another way to store 3.333E+15 directly in to the double result variable. I saw many tutorials but can we actually change the format of decimal while parsing it.?

Comment: Sure, just store the value `3.333e15` in your `double` variable. However, due to the way how `double` works, it's not guaranteed that you get that exact value. Which, for the defined use cases of `double` is fine. It's for representing either very large or very small numbers with the same data type. If you need defined *decimal* precision, then you shouldn't use `double`, but `decimal`.