# How to always show 3 numbers after decimal point C#

Tags: c#

I am currently displaying a number that is being rounded to 3 decimal places e.g. 0.31, using Math.Pow, the only problem is I want to display this number to say 0.310 (for styling purposes) does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Sure, take a look at the ToString method and giving it the formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx and also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This question was said to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814190/limiting-double-to-3-decimal-places Looking at the answers, it's clear a different question was being asked there. The question here is not involving a value that simply should have been computed using `decimal`.  If you really do want to use `double` or `float`, then doing something like `Math.Truncate(x * 1000) / 1000` isn't going to work. For example, `0.001` is not exactly represented by any `double`, but if you do `((double)0.001).ToString("F3") you will get "0.001".

Answer (score 8):

The [Fixed-Point Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#FFormatString) can be used in a call to `ToString` or in `string.Format`:

```
double x = 1493.1987;
string s1 = x.ToString("F3");
string s2 = string.Format("Your total is {0:F3}, have a nice day.", x);
// s1 is "1493.199"
// s2 is "Your total is 1493.199, have a nice day."
```

Note that the Fixed-Point Format Specifier will *always* show the number of decimal digits you specify.  For example:

```
double y = 1493;
string s3 = y.ToString("F3");
// s3 is "1493.000"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the format in the `toString`

```
double pi = 3.1415927;
string output = pi.ToString("#.000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated example that also works w/o having to call .ToString():

```
float a = 12.3578f;
double b = 12.3578d;
Console.WriteLine("The tolerance specs are: {0:F4} and: {1:F3}", a,b);
```

ANSWER: The tolerance specs are: 12.3578 and: 12.358